# How can the color of a UI Label be changed

Tags: iphone, code-documentation

What is the syntax to change the color of a UILabel?

Also, where can this information be found?

Comment: Shishir, you have 3 good answers here.  Any one of them is a direct response to your question and they have been around for over a year.  You really should choose one of them and accept the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you even look at the documentation for [UILabel](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html)? That should always be your first port of call :)

Answer (score 5):

```
myLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
```